# jboss 5 - determine if ear deployed

Tags: jboss, jmx

I am writing a Linux shell script to determine if an ear file is deployed on Jboss 5.1.  As I browse JMX console where this app is deployed, I am unsure which Mbean to query using twiddle.  On the JBoss forums, it was suggested to search for an MBean:

```
jboss.j2ee:service=EARDeployment,url='myapp.ear'
```

This was for Jboss 4.  I am unable to find this in JMX console for Jboss 5.1.  Any help would be appreciated.

Edit #1:  I also need to start and stop the entire ear in this script.